# PHP explode, grab URL's from search engine

Tags: php, url, explode, web-crawler

I currently have a script that will crawl yahoo etc to extract the links. It's working however I'm attempting to explode and get rid of http:// off of the link and / at the end (Anything after / aswell).

```
if ($href->getAttribute('class') == 'yschttl spt') {
                $link = explode('?', urldecode(array_pop(explode('**', $href->getAttribute('href')))));
                $urls[] = $link[0];
            }
```

I've not really used explode before so I'm just removing the whole line somehow. The above example returns all of the url:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q

For example. However I need it to return:

finance.yahoo.com

I am using code from http://aroussi.com/freebies/scraper/dl/fus1.zip

Comment: have you try `parse_url()` ?

Comment: see : http://codepad.org/LbUuLBRP

Comment: can you paste value of `$href->getAttribute('href')`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M8isrvDv This is the entire function.